# how to make a border around content

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want the `<div class="ghassar">` to create a border around my content, but when ever i try to make the border all the content disappear , how can i make a border around the content without making them disappearing. I think when ever i create a border it hide the content behind it, is there any way of fixing this problem, and how can i make space between the content without using the tag `<br>`
and for the div tag shall i use class or id

**HTML**

```
<div class="ghassar">
    <div id="op">
        <label>Number of days</label>
        <select name="days">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
        <br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to the basket" name="rent" id="buttom1" />
    </div>
    <br><br><br><br>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ghassar {
    margin-left: 600px;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2k9Ys/)**

Comment: The code above is rather messed up. Please create a fiddle so we can clearly see what you're trying to do in order to help.

Comment: It works fine for me though.

Comment: Your border works fine, but you have a `margin-left` of 600 pixels; its being pushed off the screen more than likely.

Comment: don't forget to mark an answer as the correct one :o

Answer (score 3):

I cleaned up the HTML a bit, and the border is working fine [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ey34/):

```
<div class="ghassar">
    <div id="op">
        <label>Number of days</label>
        <select name="days">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="add-to-basket">
        <input type="submit" value="Add to the basket" name="rent" id="buttom1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

> *and how can i make space between the content without using the tag `<br>`*

You can use margins, like I did here:

```
#add-to-basket { margin: 50px auto; position: relative; }
```

> *and for the div tag shall i use class or id*

It depends on what you're doing. Elements on the page can't share the same id, but multiple elements can have the same class.

---

**Update:** As mentioned in the other answers, you should also set the border color if you don't want the default. You can do that either with the shorthand way:

```
border:2px solid #f00; /* #f00 is the color red*/
```

or

```
border-color: #f00
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.ghassar{
    width:300px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    border-radius:25px;
}
```

Try to keep your code tidier, please.

You forgot to add a color to your border property.

Comment: Never said it was better? Just recommended to keep it tidier.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a color on your CSS border attribute. Try changing it to

`border: 2px solid black;`

Also just a tip - please make your indentation more readable. You should indent nested child elements further than parent elements.

[Here's the corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyberneticlove/VasVJ/) and [result](http://jsfiddle.net/cyberneticlove/VasVJ/embedded/result/) via jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Add color to the border.  Without it no border visible.

```
border: 2px solid #FF0000;
```